# Angular pass to @Input a multiline string right in the template

Tags: angular, angular-template

The thing I would like to do is :

```
  <app-preview
     [title]="'Some words 
     'which' "can" <be> 
     `surrounded` by any quotes
      and located in several lines
    '"
  </app-preview>
```

I would like to pass not a property of component which contains a multiline string, I would like to pass it right in the template.

How can I achieve this?

PS - variables do not work for me because the strings I am passing - are html, which are unique for every `SubComponent` which get data by `@Input`.

Example of string I'm trying to pass :

```
  <app-preview
    [title]="'Default (disabled)'"
    [lang]="'html'"
    [code]="
      <am-input
        [placeholder]="'Placeholder'"
        [disabled]="true">
      </am-input>
   ">
  </app-preview>
```

[image: making demo of components used in the project]

`ngFor` is also inappropriate with that grid, since I am defining every Section and DemoComponent right in the Page Component

[image]

Comment: Why do you want to do it in the template? What do you want the rendered result to be?

Comment: @jonrsharpe because my `Component` has about 60 `SubComponents` which must receive unique for each `SubComponent` multiline string. Creating 60 properties in `Component` for that  I consider as a bad solution

Comment: Why would you create 60 properties? Just have an `ngFor` over a property that's an *array* of those inputs. That would be neater than 60 sub-components in the template, too.

Comment: @jonrsharpe `ngFor` wont work in my situation, interface of the app and the purpose of my problem do not allow that

Comment: *"my situation, interface of the app and the purpose of my problem"* - that's what I'm asking you to provide, so people don't end up answering [an XY problem](http://xyproblem.info). Please [edit] the question.

Comment: @jonrsharpe done that

Comment: That doesn't really explain why you couldn't do something else, though. *Why* is `ngFor` inappropriate? It seems like you're going to end up with a repetitive and not very readable template. Also, note that e.g. `[title]="'Default (disabled)'"` can be written `title="Default (disabled)"`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks for tip with  [title]=.. . Code wont be repetitve, cuz I gonna dynamically generate components from these strings and generate highlighted code below them. Contrary, It would be more readeble, cuz if I specify templates in .ts file - in my opinion, it would be not that good to move from one file to another to check template of my `pageComponent` - I set every `Section` and `demoComponent` right inside it. And if I get the answer for the question - I will have just one string which provides me both with component and highlighted html below it.

Comment: @jonrsharpe my question is not about architecture and purposes. It is simple - is it possible to pass multiline string to `@Input` right in the template. For any reason and purpose. If yes - how? thanks

Comment: Then the short answer is: no. You cannot put arbitrary markup into an attribute like that. Particularly not where you expect it to somehow get rendered into the output.

Comment: Just use `[input]="'hello\nworld'"`. http://plnkr.co/edit/4SUgZgwZJfUUSMPa4XLE?p=preview

Comment: @JBNizet and what about quotes? \n is just for breaking line

Comment: quotes are harder. Haven't found a way yet.

Comment: @JBNizet hope there is a way to do this simply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is: no, you cannot put arbitrary markup into attributes in the template like that. However, what you can do (which is probably more Angular-y) is move the configuration into the component class and DRY out the template:

```ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeHtml } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'sst-styleguide',
  template: `
    <h1>Style Guide</h1>
    <div *ngFor="let section of sections">
      <h2>{{ section.name }}</h2>
      <div *ngFor="let component of section.components">
        <h3>{{ component.title }}</h3>
        <div [innerHtml]="safeMarkup(component.markup)"></div>
        <pre>{{ component.markup }}</pre>
      </div>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class StyleguideComponent {
  sections = [
    {
      name: 'Input',
      components: [
        {
          title: `
            Some words 
            'which' "can" <be> 
            \`surrounded\` by any quotes
            and located in several lines
          `,
          markup: `
            <button>Hello</button>
          `,
        },
      ],
    },
  ];

  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }

  safeMarkup(markup: string): SafeHtml {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(markup);
  }
}
```

Note that the backticks need to be escaped, but everything else in the title is left as-is.

Rendered HTML:

```html
<sst-styleguide _ngcontent-c0="">
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "[object Object]"
}--><div>
      <h2>Input</h2>
      <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "[object Object]"
}--><div>
        <h3>
            Some words 
            'which' "can" &lt;be&gt; 
            `surrounded` by any quotes
            and located in several lines
          </h3>
        <div>
            <button>Hello</button>
          </div>
        <pre>
            &lt;button&gt;Hello&lt;/button&gt;
          </pre>
      </div>
    </div>
  </sst-styleguide>
```

Obviously in practice I'd break up the `StyleguideComponent` into separate nested components to make it easier to develop and test.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it within template you can use `CDATA`. But first you need to create directive like:

```
@Directive({
  selector: 'preview-code'
})
export class CodeDirective {
  constructor(public elRef: ElementRef) {}

  get code() {
    return this.elRef.nativeElement.textContent.trim();
  }
}
```

then your template will look as:

```
<app-preview title="Default">
  <preview-code>
    <![CDATA[
    <am-input
      placeholder="Placeholder"
      [disabled]="false">
    </am-input>
    ]]>
  </preview-code>
</app-preview>
```

and inside `AppPreview` component you will be able to get `code` by:

```
@ContentChild(CodeDirective) codeDir;

ngOnInit() {
  const template = this.codeDir.code;
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/IPns6bTovhuPJAyswzmS?p=preview)**